# Selenium, item sent do database, python

Tags: python, sql, database, testing, web

I wonder if is there any way in Selenium to verify or check if item was saved to sql database via python language ? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Not in Selenium itself - you would have to code it, using a Python library to connect to the SQL database you want, and perform the queries required for what you want.

Comment: Thank a lot for answer and help